# Change labels on 'Nickname' and 'Biographical Info' in user-edit.php

Tags: functions, users, dashboard

For a project I'm working on, I want to change the labels of the 'Nickname' and 'Biographical Info' fields on edit profile (user-edit.php) page in the dashboard. I still want to use those fields as they are, I only want to change the labels. Anyone know of a function that can do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every string goes through `translate()`, which uses the `gettext` filter. This mean you can try something like this:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse6096_gettext', 10, 2 );
function wpse6096_gettext( $translation, $original )
{
    if ( 'Nickname' == $original ) {
        return 'Funny name';
    }
    if ( 'Biographical Info' == $original ) {
        return 'Resume';
    }
    return $translation;
}
```

It's probably even more efficient if you only call the `add_filter` when you are on the `user-edit.php` page (see the `admin_head-user-edit.php` hook or something like that).

Answer (score 3):

I am late with answer, but here is my take anyway. Slight differences and that selective filter add.

```
add_action('admin_head-user-edit.php', 'setup_user_edit');

function setup_user_edit() {

    add_filter('gettext', 'change_profile_labels');
}

function change_profile_labels($input) {

    if ('Nickname' == $input)
        return 'Nickname replacement';

    if ('Biographical Info' == $input)
        return 'Biographical Info replacement';

    return $input;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works...almost. It changes the labels when an admin is viewing another user but it doesn't change the labels when a user is editing their own profile. Is there a different function to use other than 'admin_head-user-edit.php'

Comment: @John Chandler `admin_head-user-edit.php` is not a function, but hook with dynamically generated name. So if you want this to run on more pages, hook it to more `admin_head-`hooks, appending suffixes accordingly.

Comment: Thx. Still getting used to work with functions and learning all the language.

Comment: You'll want `admin_head-profile.php` as well.