# Translating a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, translation

How do I go about translating custom taxonomy terms?

I am essentially trying to allow authors to see the terms in English and let the subscribers see the terms in Spanish.

I am not running a multilingual site in the sense that posts and such are translated, so plugins like qTranslate don't address my need.

The closest thing I've seen is an old plugin called [ZDMultilang](http://blog.zen-dreams.com/blog-en/wordpress/zdmultilang/) which supports term translation (tags, categories and link categories).

I've also found some solutions like this one - [Change labels on 'Nickname' and 'Biographical Info' in user-edit.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6096/change-labels-on-nickname-and-biographical-info-in-user-edit-php):

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse6096_gettext', 10, 2 );
function wpse6096_gettext( $translation, $original )
{
    if ( 'Nickname' == $original ) {
        return 'Funny name';
    }
    if ( 'Biographical Info' == $original ) {
        return 'Resume';
    }
    return $translation;
}
```

But a) it doesn't seem to be working on my site, and b) I'd need to add a conditional that checks the language the user has selected to view the site in (I suppose `get_bloginfo('language')`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself but theoretically it should work. It just requires some hacking.

First of all, this involves using **qTranslate**. If you don't want a multilingual site, you can always fill **only** the default language. Then to **force display only the default language** on the post pages, you will need to modify the core qTranslate file:

http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1777#p8303

And to **enable translation for custom taxonomy terms**, you need to create a function:

http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2045&start=0#p7380

Hopefully, this will fulfill your needs.