# Change label for registration Fields

Tags: functions, custom-field, users, user-registration

I want to change Label of Username and website on add user page and profile page.

[image]

I also looking for a way to change username label on list users and hide mail column

[image]

I'm looking for a way by adding code on function.php

Comment: try use translate(), which uses the gettext filter. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6096/change-labels-on-nickname-and-biographical-info-in-user-edit-php

Comment: I tried but it's does not work